# Getting this error message "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver"

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have created a small table in sql developer and I need to retrieve the information from that database in randomise order and then rewrite, however i am new in development i have spent a lot of time to open a connection but cannot get it I keep getting `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver`.

the code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class nameApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Connection connection;
        try {                
            connection =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.244.227.86:1522:CMARRP1T", "User1","User1");
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to put the JDBC driver JAR file in your classpath when you run your program.

Answer (score 0):

Have this before you assign a connection

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

Comment: thank you for awnsering, it says i need to put it in another try and catch statement when i do thati then get error  "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:139)
 at nameApp.main(nameApp.java:20)"

Comment: include ojdbc14.jar and place it in your classpath

Comment: @CRIS That's because you don't have the JDBC driver JAR file in your classpath.

Comment: @Jesper i find my ojdbc but can only find ojdbc5 file with the directory C:\Documents and Settings\1193672\Desktop\SQL DEVELOPER\jdbc\lib. I do apologise but its the first time i am having to use this, how would i change the above code in order to assign it to ojdbc 5

Comment: Using `Class.forName()` is not necessary with JDBC 4 (Java 6) compliant drivers; having the driver on the classpath is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class nameApp {





     public static void main(String[] args) {


        Connection connection;
        try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                connection =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.244.227.86:1522:CMARRP1T", "User1","User1");
            connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also Make sure the Ojdbc Driver is present in your Class Path. That Should get you working.

Comment: thank you for anwsering , i have done it which lead to me having to add a throws declaration however when i run it i now get the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:139)
 at nameApp.main(nameApp.java:16)"                               How do i find the location of my driver as i am guessing this is the issue here

Comment: You will need to add ojdbc.jar file in your Class path. If you are Using Netbeans, right click on project, properties, Libraries, Add Jar file. You can check this Link on how to add Jar files to Classpath in Netbeans https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html